# how to stop pandas from inferring string value "Infinity" as inf and changing datatype to float64

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, infinity

I have a dataset with a column "Vendor" and it has multiple values as "Infinity", when I use `read_csv`, pandas automatically converted the Vendor column values to `inf` and changed its datatype to `float64`.

This is the test dataset I am using

```
Vendor, Value
Infinity,1
Infinity,2
Infinity,3
Infinity,4
Infinity,5
```

This is the result I am getting with `inf` value and datatype as `float64`

```
Vendor  Value
inf     1
inf     2
inf     3
inf     4
inf     5
Name: Vendor, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to avoid default infering of `Infinity` to `inf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `dtype` argument to set explicit column types for particular column names, like so:

```
pd.read_csv(file_name, dtype={'Vendor': str})
```